# Posicionar <span>button en un determinado lugar

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente div con estas caracteristicas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO HTML**

```
<div id="arrastreImagen">
     <span><i class="fa fa-times btn btn-danger"></i></span>
     <div id="imagenBeer"><img src="~/Content/assets/birras/imperial.png" 
     class="img-thumbnail"></div>
</div>
```

**CODIGO CSS**

```
#arrastreImagen {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    color: #999;
    padding: 20px;
}

#arrastreImagen #imagenBeer {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 75px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Como puedo posicionar el boton "x" en la esquina superior derecha y que no me quede solo arriba de la imagen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Al tag `span` le podrías hacer esto:

```
#arrastreImagen span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 6px;
}
```

```css
#arrastreImagen {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    color: #999;
    padding: 2px;
}

#arrastreImagen span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 6px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius:3px;
}

#arrastreImagen img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="arrastreImagen">
     <span><i class="fa fa-times btn btn-danger"></i></span>
     <div id="imagenBeer">
        <img src="https://www.anipedia.net/imagenes/que-comen-los-perros.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Editado, mejor que reposicionar al tag `i`, es hacerlo sobre tag `span` que es el "wrapper" de `i`